# Make highlight table row without external library using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, highlight

Is there any possibility to Highlight a table row without external JS Library but using just JavaScript?

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nom</th>
<th>n°</th>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
<td class="listeitem">Denis PAPIN</td>
<td class="listeitem">7</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
<td class="listeitem">Albert EINSTEIN</td>
<td class="listeitem">2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
<td class="listeitem">Nikola TESLA</td>
<td class="listeitem">18</td>
</tr>
(…)
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the row you want to highlight? We need some context here. But yes it's entirely possible

Comment: can you explain more : small example.